# No transitions and other issues on jQuery Mobile single and multi-page website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm really struggling to load a multi-page template with Phonegap and using jQuery.

Here I have two pages (`home` and `1`) but when I load the page it just displays the second "page" div (`1`, not `home`) and no link changes the page.

With the pages as two separate .html files I could not get the transitions to work - and here I'm a step even further behind, as I can't even change pages!

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div id="header"><h1>Title</h1></div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="scroller">
                <div id="content">
                    <a href="#1" data-transition="slide">Link to Page 2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"><a href="about.html"><div class="footer_abt"></div></a></div>
    </div>


    <div data-role="page" id="1">
        <div id="header"><h1>Tummy Time</h1></div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="scroller">
                <div id="content">
                    <!-- Content Here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <a href="#home"><div class="footer_home"></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile, to the best of my knowledge, is not meant to work for multiple static pages. I mean, I guess you could do that, but I doubt any of the transitions would work. Further, it definitely won't work if you compile via PhoneGap.

If you want multiple views, I would suggest switching to an MVC js framework like Backbone.js or Sencha Touch.